# Regex to limit the instance count of any character in a string

Tags: regex

Can a Regex limit the instance count of any character in a string to, say, 5?

For example: abacaada would fail (or match) because of 5 instances of the character a.

To clarify, I was looking for any character, not just 'a'. I.e. no character can repeat more than x times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
^(?:(.)(?!(?:.*?\1){4}))*$
```

#### Working Demo: http://regex101.com/r/nG2dL4

#### Exlanation

[image]

Comment: +1 I like how you included the explanation as well :). I posted a variation of this. I did not find that marking the ".*" for all preceding characters as non-greedy / lazy made a difference.

Comment: This looks to me like it only matches if there are 4 consecutive matching characters further in the string, for a total of 5, but I think the OP wanted 5 total without limitations on where they are located within the string. So `abcdeaaaa` would match, but `abacadaea` would not, and they both should.

Comment: Ok, I stand corrected. I did look before, but evidently didn't understand the first time. The match works inverted from what I expected, I was expecting it to match if the result was invalid, not match if it was valid. Excellent work!

Comment: What is the OPPOSITE of this?  Say you wanted to match on strings that  had N+ occurrences of a certain character.

Comment: That should be: `^(?:(.)(?=(?:.*?\1){4}))*$`

Comment: @anubhava can you tell me how to modify this Regex as to include any character but exclude only white spaces? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you tell me an example string that you want to match?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
(.)(?=(?:.*\1){4})
```

It is very similar to the accepted answer, but uses a Positive Lookahead. It also matches, rather than excludes, a string if any particular character occurs *at least* 5 times.

The trick, for both this answer and the accepted answer, for matching "any character" is using the `\1` to dynamically make use of whatever was captured by the first capturing group.

Comment: No reason for the down-vote? Odd given that this pattern does answer the question as stated (the "match" scenario, not the "exclude").

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work on a few of my tests (including your case)

```
(.*a.*){5}
```

This of course ignores whitespace. If you want this constrained to specific words, you can wrap the regex in `\b`'s

```
\b(.*a.*){5}\b
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer. +1. You might want to use `dotall` too

Comment: true that seems is the easiest way

Comment: -1 This doesn't answer the actual question which is: X number of instances of ANY character, not a single given character such as "a". That was just an example. But if it was a single, given character, then Yes, this would have been the correct answer.

Comment: No it doesn't, but substituting that character in as a general case is much simpler than trying to write a regex that handles the same case.

Comment: NOTE: this **only works** for a *minimum* of 5 occurrences. Anything more than 5 still matches because of the `.`s.

Comment: Thanks. But, I was looking for any character, not just 'a'. I.e. no character can repeat more than x times.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this pattern to check a string:

```
^(?!.*(.)(?:.*\1){4})
```

pattern details:

```
^                # start anchor
(?!              # negative lookahead: not followed by
    .*           # zero or more characters
    (.)          # a captured character in group 1
    (?:.*\1){4}  # some character and the captured character repeated 4 times
)
```